# Task.WhenAll taking a long time to return

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a kiosk C# application in the field where we're trying to provide a consistent end-user experience.  Part of that is showing a brief "processing" screen for a minimum of 2 seconds while we do any server communication, since we're running over a 3G network.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

Task t1 = Task.Delay(2000);
Task<Customer> t2 = Task.Run<Customer>(() =>
{
    return _client.LookupCustomer(cardNumber, pin);
});

await Task.WhenAll(t1, t2);
customer = t2.Result;
sw.Stop();
Log.InfoFormat("Time for ValidateCustomer {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

Here is the code for `LookupCustomer`.  The "PayStationClient" constructor is empty, so there is no more hidden logic except what WCF does under the scenes.

```
    public DTO.Customer LookupCustomer(string cardNumber, string PIN)
    {
        PayStationClient client = new PayStationClient();
        decimal accountBalance, availableWithdrawalAmount, maxDailyWithdrawalAmount;

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        bool isValid = client.ValidatePin(cardNumber, PIN, out accountBalance, out availableWithdrawalAmount, out maxDailyWithdrawalAmount);

        sw.Stop();
        Log.InfoFormat("Time for LookupCustomer {0}", sw.Elapsed.ToString());

        DTO.Customer customer = new DTO.Customer()
        {
            ResponseStatus = (isValid) ? null : new ResponseStatus("Invalid PIN"),
            AccountBalance = accountBalance,
            AvailableWithdrawalAmount = availableWithdrawalAmount,
            MaxDailyWithdrawalAmount = maxDailyWithdrawalAmount,
            CardNumber = cardNumber
        };

        return customer;
    }
```

The problem is that my logs show this taking >20-30 seconds, while separate logging (client-side) in the `LookupCustomer` show the server call is returning in < 1-2 seconds.  Where does all the extra time go?  What am I missing with the `WhenAll`?

**I forgot to mention** that when the kiosk first goes online, it seems to behave as expected.  Its only after its been running for a while - 8+ hours - that the slowdown starts.  After a reboot, we're back to normal.

These kiosks have been deployed for several months, and we just added the asynchronous logic this week.  We've never had a server-side slow-down before.  Its like *something* in the first snippet is what did it.

Comment: Are you sure nothing is causing your LookupCustomer code to take longer than what the logs show? perhaps put another stopwatch inside the labmada and time how long it takes to run.

Comment: I ask because it looks like you did everything right so LookupCustomer taking extra time is the only explanation.

Comment: I agree, but this slowdown was only introduced after the addition of the async logic.  LookupCustomer has remained unchanged in the last serveral months of field deployment.

Comment: What sort of logic happens in the `PayStationClient()` constructor? That seems to be conspicuously outside your `Stopwatch` timer, so perhaps the problem lies in there?

Comment: @HarrisonPaine  Nothing - just `public PayStationClient() {}`.  Perhaps there is some WCF plumbing, but again, what would slow down only after the uptime is several hours?

Comment: @jklemmack, I suggest your put another stopwatch timing just around `return _client.LookupCustomer(cardNumber, pin)` line. What does it show?

Comment: Agree with @Noseratio, this could be issued by some Dispose() issue with your PayStationClient or API call. Try maybe using(PayStationClient client = new PayStationClient()){...}

Comment: @GuillaumePelletier Fantastic idea, and good practice anyway.  I'll give it a shot, and see how it looks in a day or two.  Sucks that this only appears in the field, and after a "long" time.